# Hibernate update object best practice

Tags: java, hibernate

for example I have these "simplified" classes:

```
class Employer {
    int employerId;
    String name;
    Department department;
}

class Department {
    int id;
    String name;
}
```

which are the recommended way to do a update in hibernate(change employer's department)

doing (object way)

```
Employer e = employerDao.getById(id);
e.setDepartment(new Department(newIdDept));
dao.save(e)
```

or write dao function with a update hql like (sql way):

```
update set idDepartment=:newId where employerId=:id
```

and them, just call  `dao.updateDepartment(employerId, newDptId);`

Answer (score 0):

You should use `SaveOrUpdate()` method. This method calls either `save()` or `update()` on the whenever which is required. If the data is present in the database, update query is executed.

Comment: What is the benefit to using `saveOrUpdate` instead of `save`? At a guess it would impact index insertion, partitioning, triggers and therefore performance; is that correct?